# HDFS Replication - Data Stored

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am a relative newbie to hadoop and want to get a better understanding of how replication works in HDFS.

Say that I have a 10 node system(1 TB each node), giving me a total capacity of 10 TB. If I have a replication factor of 3, then I have 1 original copy and 3 replicas for each file. So, in essence, only 25% of my storage is original data. So my 10 TB cluster is in effect only 2.5 TB of original(un-replicated) data.

Please let me know if my train of thought is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your thinking is a little off.  A replication factor of 3 means that you have 3 ***total*** copies of your data.  More specifically, there will be 3 copies of each block for your file, so if your file is made up of 10 blocks there will be 30 total blocks across your 10 nodes, or about 3 blocks per node.

You are correct in thinking that a 10x1TB cluster has less than 10TB capacity- with a replication factor of 3, it actually has a functional capacity of about 3.3TB, with a little less actual capacity because of space needed for doing any processing, holding temporary files, etc.

Comment: Thanks Chris ! I am trying to understand the internals of how this works. Say I do a scan to look for a particular pattern, will this scan happen for all 3 copies of each block in the file, or just the original/first copy of the block ?

Comment: Just one copy of the block.  The copy that is chosen is random- there is no "master" copy.