# Replication factor

Tags: hadoop, replication

I am new to Hadoop and I want to understand how do we determine the highest replication factor we can have for any given cluster. I know that the default setting is 3 replicas, but if I have a cluster with 5  node what is the highest replication factor that I can user in that case. Is there a formula that we have to follow to determine the replication factor?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The highest replication factor that you can use is a function of the number of nodes in your cluster (as @Tarik said, you cannot have more replicas than nodes in your cluster), your expected usage (how much data do you plan to store) AND your cluster's storage capacity.

This other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708298/hdfs-replication-data-stored?rq=1) has some calculations on capacity and storage use.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you cannot have more replicas than nodes as storing two copies on the same node is useless. It seems to me to be the upper limit.

Answer (score 0):

In the Hadoop environment, the default replication factor is 3 for 3 slave machines or more than that. Here is a simple formula for that is 'N' Replication Factor = 'N' Slave Nodes. Here is more info about replication http://commandstech.com/replication-factor-in-hadoop/