# How data copy on hadoop Node

Tags: hadoop, dictionary, reduce

I want to know how data is distributed on hadoop cluster nodes.

I have a cluster with 3 nodes. I want to copy 3GB data on HDFS. My question is,
when I execute the command

```
hadoop dfs -put /readme.txt /review/readme.txt
```

will the data be copied on all 3 nodes? How will the data be distributed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HDFS Replication - Data Stored](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708298/hdfs-replication-data-stored)

Comment: Thanks blackSmith, when I execute above command hadoop automatically distribute data on node(question may be silly for you)

Comment: It's not silly at all, folks using HDFS should know how data is stored. I would've add an answer, but that question seems to suffice your need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have 3GB of data and not changed the default **replication factor** (3), then you will store approximately 9GB on your nodes.

Replication factor is the number of copies that will be created on the cluster.

Your data will be split into blocks, each of 124MB max (default maximum block size in the new API). Then, each block will be copied twice and sent to different nodes.

There are, I think, two reasons to have data replicated:

1. **Data locality**: It is faster to process data stored locally, than get data from the network and then process it.
2. **Backup**: Hadoop nodes often fail. If they hold a portion of the input data and you have no backup, then the whole job will fail. On the other hand, if you keep copies on other nodes too, then a single node failure will not influence the job a lot.

blackSmith is right, that [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708298/hdfs-replication-data-stored) contains an answer to your question, but perhaps you were not familiar with the key notion of data replication.